# GROUP_CONCAT Alternative in Netezza?

Tags: netezza

I am trying to do a GROUP_CONCAT in Netezza but am getting an "ERROR: EXECUTE AGG: permission denied". It seems you need a certain add-on for this function and I do not have the ability to add that. I am wondering if there are any workarounds to this. Here is what I am trying to do:

| ID | DX_CODE | DX_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122334 | M97 | 1 |
| 122334 | M98 | 2 |
| 144556 | M97 | 1 |
| 177889 | M97 | 2 |
| 177889 | M98 | 3 |
| 199005 | M97 | 3 |

I want to combine the DX_CODES by DX_ORDER into one unique row per ID:

| ID | DX_CODES |
| --- | --- |
| 122334 | M97; M98 |
| 144556 | M97 |
| 177889 | M97; M98 |
| 199005 | M97 |

I tried doing a MAX(CASE) statement like this...

```
(MAX(CASE WHEN DX.DX_ORDER = 2 THEN DX.DX_CODE ELSE '' END)||
    MAX(CASE WHEN DX.DX_ORDER = 3 THEN '; ' || DX.DX_CODE ELSE '' END)) AS DX2
```

which works if there is both a DX_ORDER 2 and 3 but if there is only an order 3 then I get something that looks like this:

| ID | DX_CODES |
| --- | --- |
| 199005 | ; M97 |

Is there any way to incorporate all of these together to get something cleaner that does not give me separators when there is nothing to separate?

LIST_AGG in Oracle would work perfect but Netezza seems to be lacking when it comes to this.